# Android Bluetooth runtime user permission request dialogue disappears immeadiately after creation. How to solve it?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm trying to request runtime user permission in an Android program using the `ActivityResultLauncher#launch()` function. It's supposed to make a permissions dialogue requesting the user to grant the requested permission. But in my program, the dialogue disappears in less than half a second. Could you please point out what I got wrong?

I requested the permission in the main activity using this code snippet:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth scan permission denied. Requesting...");
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission requested. Awaiting user response");
        return;
}
```

`requestPermissionLauncher` is defined in the activity as fallows:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
            if (isGranted) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Requested permission granted!");
                scanLeDevice();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Requested permission denied!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied! Sorry, we can't continue.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
```

Some selected Logcat messages are as fallows:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (4871) for package com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer ----------------------------
...
2023-06-11 19:57:01.623  4871-4871  important_info          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      I  Bluetooth scan permission denied. Requesting...
2023-06-11 19:57:01.648  4871-4871  important_info          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      I  Permission requested. Awaiting user response
2023-06-11 19:57:01.709  4871-4871  ActivityThread          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{af555b6 token=android.os.BinderProxy@5980385 {com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer/com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@5980385
2023-06-11 19:57:01.720  4871-4871  ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe    com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  notify runnable to start.
2023-06-11 19:57:01.737  4871-4871  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  Skia GL Pipeline
2023-06-11 19:57:01.750  4871-4871  HwAppInnerBoostImpl     com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  set config for com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer BOOST_FLAG=false REPORT_DURATION_CLICK=1000 REPORT_TIMES_CLICK=3 REPORT_DURATION_SLIDE=5000 REPORT_TIMES_SLIDE=16
2023-06-11 19:57:01.753  4871-4871  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D    HWUI Binary is  enabled
2023-06-11 19:57:01.753  4871-4871  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  disableOutlineDraw is true
2023-06-11 19:57:01.792  1263-1506  HiDATA_HiNetwork        system_server                        E  monitor handleActivityChange curPkgName is com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer curUid is 10174 lastPkgName is :com.huawei.android.launcher
2023-06-11 19:57:01.796  4871-4871  ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe    com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  stop checker.
2023-06-11 19:57:01.802  1263-1506  HiDATA_HiNetwork        system_server                        E  onAppStart packageName is com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer
2023-06-11 19:57:01.803  1263-1506  HiDATA_HiNetwork        system_server                        E  contain db file packageName: com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer iscanacce:-1
2023-06-11 19:57:01.806  1730-10535 DollieAdapterService    com.huawei.systemserver              E  notifyActivityState pkg:com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer/com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer.MainActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10174
...
2023-06-11 19:57:11.906  4871-4871  important_info          com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      E  Requested permission denied!
2023-06-11 19:57:11.919  4871-4871  ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe    com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      D  notify runnable to start.
2023-06-11 19:57:11.936  4871-4871  InputMethodManager      com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer      W  startInputReason = 1
2023-06-11 19:57:11.937  1263-1506  HiDATA_HiNetwork        system_server                        E  monitor handleActivityChange curPkgName is com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer curUid is 10174 lastPkgName is :com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer
2023-06-11 19:57:11.938  1730-10535 DollieAdapterService    com.huawei.systemserver              E  notifyActivityState pkg:com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer/com.example.ble_imu_data_viewer.MainActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10174
...
```

I have declared the requested permission, `BLUETOOTH_SCAN`, in the Manifest file via

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

The entire sorce code and complete Logcat content are available below:

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://pastebin.com/bu61uKFk)

[MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/4NenQiK7)

[build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/3izkyhrC)

[Complete Logcat content](https://pastebin.com/YzZDTjar)

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to solve this myself.

Whilst I declared the BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permissions in my manifest file, they are not the right permissions to ask in my context. These two permissions are only suitable for Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, but my app runs on Android 9 (API level 28). For Android versions equal to or lower than 11 (API level 30), the app needs to request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION for API level 28 or lower) permission at runtime instead.

For more detailed (and important) information, please refer to [Bluetooth permissions | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).